# Cauchy-Hadamard confusion

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, analysis, convergence-divergence, proof-explanation

I was reading the proof [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Hadamard_theorem#Proof_of_the_theorem), but did not understand a few key points, so I'm asking here for the following clarifications:

(1) I don't see why $|c_n|\le (t+\varepsilon)^n$ for all but a finite number of $n$. Is there some theorem for this result in analysis?

(2) Why does (1) imply that $\sum c_nz^n$ converges for $|z|<1/(t+\varepsilon)$? We are not talking about absolute convergence here, I think, but the moduli seem to point to absolute convergence. There is probably a connection between the fact that the modulus of a complex sequence is less than one and its power series' convergence.

(3) Why does the fact that $|c_n|=(t+\varepsilon)^n$ imply that $\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}|c_n|^{1/n}=1/R$?

(4) Why is $|c_n|\ge (t-\varepsilon)^n$ for infinitely many $n$?

(5) Finally, I've seen another statement of this theorem, with the difference that $R$ was defined there as $R:=\liminf\limits_{n\to\infty}|c_n|^{-1/n}$. Why are these statements equal?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shaun is completely correct about 1. The $\limsup$ of a sequence $a_n$ is by definition the lowest value such that for all higher values, only finitely many of the $a_n$ are above them. Conversely, the $\liminf a_n$ is the largest value such that for all lower values, only finitely many values of $a_n$ are below them. Now suppose $f(x)$ is a strictly decreasing continuous function of $x$. Then $f(a_n)$ reverses every order relationship in $a_n$. If $L > \limsup a_n$, so only finitely many $a_n > L$, then only finitely many $f(a_n)$ will be below $f(L)$. For any value $Q$ less than $f(L)$ but still in the image of $f$ there is a $Q' > L$ with $f(Q') = Q$. There are infinitely many $a_n$ greater than $Q'$. But that means that there are infinitely many $f(a_n)$ that are less than $Q = f(Q')$. Which shows that $f(L) = \liminf f(a_n)$.

In particular $f(x) = \frac 1x$ is a continuous decreasing function on the positive reals. Therefore, when $\sqrt[n]{|c_n|}$ is a positive sequence, we have $$\liminf \frac 1 {\sqrt[n]{|c_n|}} = \frac 1{\limsup \sqrt[n]{|c_n|}}$$

The Wikipedia version is preferred for a simple reason: that "positive" sequence requirement. When infinitely many of the $c_n = 0$, the expression on the left requires the use of actual infinities for $\frac 10$ to define it. Of course, this can work and gives the same answer in the end because the $\liminf$ will only give $\infty$ if there is no lower limit point. But the $\limsup$ version does not require an actual infinity to work (the case when the $\limsup = 0$ can be treated as a conceptual infinity only).

As for (2), we have $|c_n| \le (t + \epsilon)^n$ and $|z| < 1/(t + \epsilon)$, so defining $k = |z|(t + \epsilon)$, this means $k < 1$. Therefore $$\sum |c_nz^n| = \sum |c_n||z^n| \le \sum  (t + \epsilon)^n|z|^n \le \sum  k^n$$ but since $k<1$, that geometric series is known to converge, and so $\sum c_nz^n$ is absolutely convergent for $|z| < 1/(t + \epsilon)$.
This shows that the radius of convergence is at least $R$.

For (3), as Shaun says, you appear to have it backwards. Because $t = 1/R$ is the limit supremum, $t - \epsilon$ is a number below the limit supremum and therefore by definition, there are infinitely many $c_n$ with $\sqrt[n]{|c_n|} > t - \epsilon$ and therefore infinitely many $c_n > (t - \epsilon)^n$. Therefore when $z = 1/(t - \epsilon)$ then there are infinitely many $|c_nz^n| > (t - \epsilon)^n(t - \epsilon)^{-n} = 1$. So it cannot be that $\lim_n c_nz^n = 0$, wich is a requirement for the series to converge. Since any value greater than $R$ can be expressed as $1/(t - \epsilon)$ for some positive $\epsilon$, no value greater than $R$ can be the radius of convergence. So $R$ must be the radius of convergence.

Note that this proof does not itself show that the series diverges for every $|z| > R$, only that there is a least one such $z$ for any radius greater than $R$. However, it would take only a minor change to prove the fuller result.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53876/discussion-between-paul-sinclair-and-sequence).

Comment: But I believe $ \limsup a_n $ the lowest $ l $ such that "for any $ \epsilon > 0 $, only finitely many $ n $ are s.t. $ a_n > l + \epsilon $" (as opposed to "... only finitely many $ n $ are s.t. $ a_n > l $"). We can take $ a_n = \dfrac{1}{n} $ for instance.

Comment: @VenkataKarthikBandaru - You are correct. I was uncautious in my wording. The lim sup is the infimum of all $l$ such that only finitely many $a_n > l$, so it is possible for the lim sup itself to have infinitely many $a_n$ above it. And similarly it is possible for the lim inf to have infinitely many $a_n$ below it.

Answer (score 1):

1. $t$ is defined by $\limsup_{n\to\infty}|c_n|^\frac{1}{n}$. If it were true that $|c_n|^\frac{1}{n}\geq t+\epsilon$ for infinitely many $n$, then the lim sup would also be $\geq t+\epsilon$.
2. Let $N$ be such that $|c_n|^\frac{1}{n}<t+\epsilon$ for all $n>N$, and assume that $|z|<1/(t+\epsilon)$. Then: $$\sum_{n} c_{n} z^n=\sum_{n =1}^Nc_{n}z^n+\sum_{n=N+1}^\infty c_nz^n<\sum_{n=1}^Nc_nz^n+\sum_{n=N+1}\frac{c_n}{(t+\epsilon)^n}<\sum_{n =1}^Nc_{n}z^n+\sum_{n>N}c_n$$ The sum of the last series is finite because both series converge; one is a finite sum, the other converges because $\sum_nc_n$ converges.
3. I'm a bit confused what you mean by this. The proof defines $\limsup_{n\to\infty}|c_n|^\frac{1}{n}=1/R$, not the other way around.
4. The reasoning is similar to 1.
5. Important not to get the notation from different proofs confused: in those proofs $R$ was the radius of convergence. In the Wikipedia article $1/R$ is the radius. Keeping that in mind see [here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/580371/lim-sup-of-a-sequence-of-postive-numbers-is-equal-to-lim-inf-of-the-inverses-of)

Hope this helps. Let me know if you want further clarification.

Comment: On 2, there is nothing that guarantees $\sum_{n>N} c_n$ converges. Rather it is because $|c_nz^n| \le ((t + \epsilon)|z|)^n = k^n$ for some $k < 1$. Hence the absolute value series is majorized by the convergent $\sum k^n$. So the original series is absolutely convergent.

Comment: Also, in the Wikipedia article $R$ is the radius of convergence, but the lim sup formula gives its inverse, not the radius itself. After all, if the coefficients fall more rapidly to $0$, one would expect the radius of convergence to increase, not decrease.